# Firebase iOS Crashlytics stuck at Add SDK

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, migration, crashlytics

My iOS app is live with Appstore.In my app ,I was using Fabric Crashlytics SDK.I missed too upgrade to updated Firebase Crashlytics SDK before 15 November 2020.Yesterday,I updated it to updated Firebase Crashlytics.But on Console it is still showing Add SDK page.
On Home Screen it shows crash details but not crash report & crash count.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a coding question here? If so, what is it? Can you include your code? Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @poojathorat Try to download the Dsym file from apple developer account and try to upload it. Then you will get the crashes.